# How to add a new TR to a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So at the moment I'm trying to add a new tr to a table that I already have, and while doing so, trying to update the rowspan of the previous tr, but I'm not getting it, so I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Here's what I've been trying to do (and what I am trying to achieve):

So here's a picture of the table that I have at the moment: [image]

Now, when I am pressing "Add Row" to "Javier", I get this (which is fine, because I'm adding the new row after the one I already have..For the moment):

[image]

If I press "Add Row" to "Palacios", I get this (which is wrong, because I'm trying to get the new row of "Palacios" after the "first" row of "Palacios").

[image]

**Problem 1**

So here is my first issue..I don't know why this is happening! Like my table should look like this if I want to add a new row of "Palacios", and not like in the third image.

[image]

**Problem 2**

As you can see in the fourth image, I have 4 rows (2 of Javier and 2 of Palacios), but what I would like to do is to change the "rowspan" of the first one, so while I'm adding more, I'm increasing the rowspan. For example, if I press "Add row" to "Javier", it should look like this:

[image]

And if I add another one, then the rowspan of Javier would be 3, and not 2...But I'm not sure how to approach any of these problems (or what I'm doing wrong in the first one)

Here's the code of that.

```js
function AddRow(row) {
  var x = document.getElementById('TablePlayers');
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  // // document.getElementById("test").rowSpan += 1;
  var new_row = x.rows[i].cloneNode(true);
  x.insertBefore(new_row, x.childNodes[i]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
<title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="TablePlayers" border="1">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Goals</td>
      <td>Add Row</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Javier</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Palacios</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing `closest` is much simpler (great suggestion, @epascarello). So I've taken that and added more onto the code which will expand the `rowSpan` property to get your desired result.

As you'll see, you want to remove the first cell of the newly-cloned row to make the `rowSpan` work properly.

Furthermore, to prevent bugs, we want to ensure we only select the MAIN row, which we do through a `while` loop.

```js
function AddRow(btn) {
  var tbody = document.querySelector('#TablePlayers tbody');
  var tr = btn.closest('tr');

  // Check if the row we're copying has all the cells
  // to ensure we expand the correct row.
  // IE: If a row only has 3 cells, when we know it doesn't have
  // the first cell with `rowSpan`
  while (tr.cells.length != 4){
    tr = tr.previousSibling;
  }

  // Expand the rowSpan of the main TR
  tr.cells[0].rowSpan+=1;

  // Clone the TR and remove its first cell
  var new_row = tr.cloneNode(true);
  new_row.deleteCell(0);

  // Inserts the new row AFTER the current one.
  // Since JavaScript doesn't have `insertAfter`, we can
  // use this trick to make it work. We're essentially
  // inserting the new row BEFORE the NEXT SIBLING
  tbody.insertBefore(new_row, tr.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
<title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="TablePlayers" border="1">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Goals</td>
      <td>Add Row</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Javier</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Palacios</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just reference the table row, no need to look up the index. Also you should be doing this from the tbody and not the table.

```js
function AddRow(btn) {
  var tbody = document.querySelector('#TablePlayers tbody');
  var tr = btn.closest('tr');
  var new_row = tr.cloneNode(true);
  tbody.insertBefore(new_row, tr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
<title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="TablePlayers" border="1">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Goals</td>
      <td>Add Row</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Javier</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Palacios</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And modern browsers you can use before() or after()

```js
function AddRow(btn) {
  var tr = btn.closest('tr');
  var new_row = tr.cloneNode(true);
  tr.after(new_row);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
<title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="TablePlayers" border="1">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Goals</td>
      <td>Add Row</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Javier</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Palacios</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" name="NUM[]"></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" name="GOALS[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much "epascarello" and @Wes Foster ! That really helped me a ton!